# When button is clicked text changing issue(Only using CSS)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to `change text` of the button "Click" to "Clicked" when button is clicked. 
Also when button is clicked its `background color` of whole button and button text should change to green and `border color` should change to red.

I have tried to solve this, But I am unable to achieve so.

```css
body{
  background-color:#7a86cb;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.button-btn #btn1 ,#btn2, #btn3{
   width:120px;
  height:45px;
  border-radius:30px;
  background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border:2px solid black;
  color:white;
 }

#btn1{
 }

#btn2{
 margin-left:15px;
}

#btn3{
 margin-left:15px;
}

.button-btn #btn1:hover,#btn2:hover,#btn3:hover{
   background-color:#7a86cb;
 }


.btn1:active,.btn2:active,.btn3:active {
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

.btn1:after{
  content:"Clicked!";
  background-color:green;
  border:red;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="center">
  <div class="button-btn">
<button href="#" id="btn1" class="btn1">Click</button>
<button href="#" id="btn2" class="btn2">Click</button>
<button href="#" id="btn3" class="btn3">Click</button>
    </div>
 </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

For changing the color of button when clicked, you can use JavaScript as follow:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( ".js-click" ).click(function() {
    $( ".js-click" ).css('background', 'green');
  });
});
```

and your CSS may like this:

```
button {
  background: none;
}
```

and your html codes:

```
<button class="js-click">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: No javascript, only with css

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to use JavaScript. Add an event listener for when the button is clicked, and either edit the style directly or add a class.

That being said, a full CSS solution is possible using hacks: [codepen](https://codepen.io/bali_balo/pen/5283e5629d5cce172c6b5362464b27d2)

```css
body {
 background-color: #7a86cb;
 margin: 20px;
}

#button1-clicked { display: none; }

.button {
 position: relative;
 width: 120px;
 height: 45px;
 text-align: center;
 white-space: nowrap;
 line-height: 45px;
 border-radius: 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 border: 2px solid black;
 color: white;
}
.button:active {
 transform: translateY(4px);
}
.button:hover {
 background: #7a86cb;
}
.button::before {
 content: 'Click';
}
.button .cover {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 1;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#button1-clicked:active ~ #button1 {
 transform: translateY(4px);
}
#button1-clicked:checked ~ #button1 {
 background: green;
 border-color: red;
}
#button1-clicked:checked ~ #button1::before {
 content: 'Clicked!'
}
/* Hide the label to make sure the user cannot "unclick" */
#button1-clicked:checked ~ #button1 .cover {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="button1-clicked">
<div class="button" id="button1" role="button">
 <label for="button1-clicked" class="cover"></label>
</div>
```

Please avoid using that kind of things in production, and use a JavaScript event listener.

Comment: Hey thanks,but could you achieve this without changing the actual HTML code?

Comment: @osama No. Without changing the HTML there is no way to have a persisting clicked state. You could only indicate when the button is active / focused.

Comment: After trying your code, my button hover and initial color properties are erased, could you please check for me

Comment: Yes I didn't copy your full code. They can be added the same way the `:active` is added. EDIT: just added the hover background change to the answer. The colors seem the same as in your example though.